# Passing check box data to another Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

The Question is
Choose an option from five checkbox selection and show the results in another page for the selected choices.

And I have 2 activity in the apps.

All the coding is done on java file without adding any code in xml file.

MainActivity.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.*;
import android.view.View.*;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Q3
                LinearLayout ll3 = new LinearLayout(this);
                ll3.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);


                final List <CheckBox> cbs = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();

                for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                    CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
                    cb.setText("Apple" + (i + 1));
                    ll3.addView(cbs.get(i));
                }



                Button button3 = new Button(this);
                button3.setText("Select");

                button3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();

                        for(int i = 0; i < cbs.size(); i++){
                            if(cbs.get(i).isChecked()){
                                str.append(cbs.get(i).getText().toString() + "; ");
                            }
                        }

                        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity2.class);
                        i.putExtra("checked", str.toString());
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });

                ll3.addView(button3);
                setContentView(ll3);
    }



}
```

And for another activity file name MainActivity2.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity2 extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2);

        //Q3
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setText("You have selected:");
                TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
                tv1.setText(this.getIntent().getStringExtra("checked"));

                LinearLayout ll3 = new LinearLayout(this);
                ll3.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                ll3.addView(tv);
                ll3.addView(tv1);
                setContentView(ll3);
    }


}
```

When I run the apps it show error message state that cannot be run. Any problem?

Logcat file

```
02-20 08:09:07.274: D/AndroidRuntime(376): Shutting down VM
02-20 08:09:07.274: W/dalvikvm(376): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
02-20 08:09:07.303: E/AndroidRuntime(376): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-20 08:09:07.303: E/AndroidRuntime(376): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.practical033/com.practical033.MainActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
02-20 08:09:07.303: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
02-20 08:09:07.303: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
02-20 08:09:07.303: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-20 08:09:07.303: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
02-20 08:09:07.303: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-20 08:09:07.303: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-20 08:09:07.303: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-20 08:09:07.303: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-20 08:09:07.303: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-20 08:09:07.303: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-20 08:09:07.303: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-20 08:09:07.303: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-20 08:09:07.303: E/AndroidRuntime(376): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
02-20 08:09:07.303: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257)
02-20 08:09:07.303: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:311)
02-20 08:09:07.303: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at com.practical033.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
02-20 08:09:07.303: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-20 08:09:07.303: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
02-20 08:09:07.303: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  ... 11 more
02-20 08:09:09.733: I/Process(376): Sending signal. PID: 376 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Haven't add your checkboxes to cbs list and you are trying to access the checkbox from it...

try add checkboxes to list by using  `cbs.add(cb);` in your for loop...

try this

```
final List <CheckBox> cbs = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();

            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
                cb.setText("Apple" + (i + 1));
                cbs.add(cb);
                ll3.addView(cbs.get(i));
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use two ways 
- use a static variable and give check box value to that variable and access that to another activity 
- use intent to pass data pass value from 1st activity and recieve in other 
sample for extra is following 
activity 1st

```
  Intent i = new Intent(FirstScreen.this, SecondScreen.class);   
String keyIdentifer  = null;
i.putExtra("STRING_I_NEED", strName);
```

activity 2nd

```
 String newString;
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras == null) {
        newString= null;
    } else {
        newString= extras.getString("STRING_I_NEED");
    }
} else {
    newString= (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("STRING_I_NEED");
}
```

use either way its upto you

Comment: yes there is an error in your code you are initalizing the ArrayList with 0 and applying loop to 5 that`s y when loop start it  tries to move to next location in array list which is not size of array list so it goes out of index and casunig app crash  initalize list

Comment: final List <CheckBox> cbs = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();

change the above code with the below

 final List <CheckBox> cbs = new ArrayList<CheckBox>(5);

Comment: No luck at all still the same force to close in emulator